# Can tsqlt table accessed outside of tSqlt scope?

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, sql-server-2012, tdd, tsqlt

I am writing a tsqlt unit testing where I am not faking the table and I am using the real SQL table ex:**sendEmail** to test the email sending functionality.

I am inserting the value like below from tsqlt to the sendEmail table

```
Email: 'test@test.com'
Status : 0
Template : 'New User Creation'
```

There is an automation job outside of tsqlt that will look for these table entries which have Status :0 process the email to the sender address and update back to the table's column value as Status:1

But I am not seeing the automation job is able to do success with email sending during this tsqlt regression scenario. Can't we access the SQL table and its value outside use when tsqlt is running? Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

tSqlt will be running only in the isolated way and can't integrate with any other code or application?

Comment: Individual tSQLt Tests are executed within a transaction context so that all changes made during the setup and test can be rolled back at the end of each test. The automation job runs outside that context (presumably it's an SQL Agent job?) so will block on table accesses until the current tSQLt Test transaction rolls back and frees its locks.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for an Integration Testing solution. tSQLt is a Unit Testing solution, so it's intended to test small, isolated pieces of code. e.g.: stored procedures, triggers and user-defined functions.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning  Make sense. Can we use tsqlt.resultsetfilter for my situation like getting sp returned value and call other job or proc? i may be completely wrong. just curious :)

Comment: While you can't test the SQL Agent job itself, you could have the job invoke a stored procedure that's in the same database as your sendEmail table and then test that stored procedure with tSQLt (i.e. in the `setup` insert row/s into the sendEmail table, test that the stored procedure does the right things with them). Bear in mind that tSQLt is limited to testing objects within the current database so if your procedure does things like call `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` you'd have to isolate that. e.g.: write a local wrapper proc around it and then SpyProcedure that wrapper in the tests.

Comment: Running tSQLt tests without the transaction is now possible with the latest version V1.0.8043.39707 as per the release note.@tSQLt:NoTransaction

Comment: @AlwaysLearning my automation job scheduled on autosys.